# How to fix python3 errror: name unicode is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am working on an openstreetmap project and have the following code

```
class UnicodeDictWriter(csv.DictWriter, object):  
            """Extend csv.DictWriter to handle Unicode input"""  

    def writerow(self, row):  
        super(UnicodeDictWriter, self).writerow({
        k: (v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v) for k, v in row.items()})  

    def writerows(self, rows):  
         for row in rows:  
             self.writerow(row)
```

It throws me the error message name unicode is not defined, research did not give a clue for solving it. How do I modify the code to a working one?  (Please be patient, I am still learning)

Answer (score 1):

It look like

```
isinstance(v, unicode)
```

appears to be a Python2 way for checking whether or not the object is unicode. With Python3, you have bytes as an instance, so try using

```
not isinstance(v, bytes)
```

instead.

Comment: `bytes` and `unicode` are opposites of each other; in order to be anywhere remotely equivalent, the second snippet should be `not isinstance(v, bytes)`.